# how to upload Sqlite database file to server from iphone application in ios

Tags: iphone, sqlite

In my iphone application i used sqlite3 for creating database. 
Now i want to take backup of a database file on my server.

so how to upload my sqlite db file to server from my application in iphone?

Answer (score 5):

I would read the sql database into a JSON object, then upload it to a server via a URL that calls a PHP script along the lines of [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941598/how-to-get-json-code-into-mysql-database)!

Here's an example of some mySQL data wrapped into JSON:

```
{database:{"col1":"56","col2":"85","col3":"some_text"},
{"col1":"57","col2":"86","col3":"next row"} }
```

More about JSON payloads in Apple dev docs here [JSON](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

As of iOS5.x, Apple now includes some JSON helper classes, see [NSJSONSerialization class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) along with the Twitter example app.

I have used this the SBJson framework in the past for iOS [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)

Comment: hello nick thanks for your reply.Instead of read sql database into a JSON object. I want to upload whole Sqlite db file similar to the upload image on server in iphone. It is possible or not.

Comment: One option is to turn on file sharing via iTunes:  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241032/share-sqlite-with-itune-file-sharing-within-ios-app